# HTML Prewiev Plugin Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am developing a JSP page. At this page there will be a textarea and users will be able to write HTML codes there. I want that, when a user writes an HTML code, there will be another field at same page and `user should see the preview of that HTML code`. User can see it while typing or pressing a button, it is not matter right now.

How can I do with maybe with a plug-in in JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should not be too hard without a plugin :)

try this:

```
$('#sometextarea').keyup(function () {
    $('#somediv').html($(this).val());
});
```

test here: http://jsfiddle.net/nvR8c/1/

(I changed it from `.change` to `.keyup` because `.change` first triggers when textarea loses focus - but if that is okay, you can change it back to `.change` which will be lighter for the browser.)